# Materialized view with AggregatingMergeTree engine removes entries instead of aggregation

Tags: clickhouse

Let's say I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE trades (
  `ts` DateTime64(9, 'UTC'), 
  `volume` Decimal(40, 20),
  `market` String
) ENGINE = MergeTree ORDER BY (market, ts)
```

and a materialized view on top of it

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW trades_per_hour 
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree()
ORDER BY (market, ts_1h)
AS (
    SELECT sum(volume) as volume, ts_1h, market
    FROM trades 
    GROUP BY market, toStartOfHour(ts) as ts_1h
)
```

I insert a couple of records there:

```
INSERT INTO trades (*) VALUES ('2021-01-01 01:08:00', '1.5', 'EUR')
INSERT INTO trades (*) VALUES ('2021-01-01 01:09:00', '3.7', 'EUR')
```

so the table looks like

```
┌────────────────────────────ts─┬─────────────────volume─┬─market─┐
│ 2021-01-01 01:08:00.000000000 │ 1.50000000000000000000 │ EUR    │
└───────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴────────┘
┌────────────────────────────ts─┬─────────────────volume─┬─market─┐
│ 2021-01-01 01:09:00.000000000 │ 3.70000000000000000000 │ EUR    │
└───────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴────────┘
```

Now, materialized view without group by displays two rows (I guess that is expected):

```
SELECT * FROM trades_per_hour;

┌─────────────────volume─┬───────────────ts_1h─┬─market─┐
│ 3.70000000000000000000 │ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 │ EUR    │
└────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴────────┘
┌─────────────────volume─┬───────────────ts_1h─┬─market─┐
│ 1.50000000000000000000 │ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 │ EUR    │
└────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴────────┘
```

if queried with group clause, it shows:

```
SELECT sum(volume), ts_1h FROM trades_per_hour GROUP BY ts_1h;

┌────────────sum(volume)─┬───────────────ts_1h─┐
│ 5.20000000000000000000 │ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 │
└────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

then, if I do

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE trades_per_hour;
```

I have only one row left (due to deduplication I guess?):

```
┌─────────────────volume─┬───────────────ts_1h─┬─market─┐
│ 1.50000000000000000000 │ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 │ EUR    │
└────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴────────┘
```

so the row with volume 3.7 was just deleted.

What I actually expect is

```
┌─────────────────volume─┬───────────────ts_1h─┬─market─┐
│ 5.20000000000000000000 │ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 │ EUR    │
└────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴────────┘
```

so the "duplicates" per ts_1h + market are actually aggregated together.

I would like to ask what I am doing wrong in my table and/or materialized view definition.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to use [AggregateFunction/SimpleAggregateFunction](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/aggregatefunction/):

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW trades_per_hour 
(
  ts_1h DateTime64(9, 'UTC'),
  volume SimpleAggregateFunction(sum, Decimal(40, 20)),
  market String
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(ts_1h)
ORDER BY (market, ts_1h)
AS 
SELECT toStartOfHour(ts) as ts_1h, sum(volume) as volume, market
FROM trades 
GROUP BY market, ts_1h
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Vladimir. Didn't know that I could define the MV schema upfront and give it a hint about the aggregation function. That works nicely!